# Old and New Azure Functions projects have lots of "The type or namespace name 'XXX' could not be found errors" after reinstall

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I recently wiped Windows and reinstalled. I also reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 Community.

Now my Azure Functions apps are full of name space errors. I tried created a brand new Azure Functions projects to copy over whatever I need to fix, but same thing:

[image]

This is a brand new project with the same errors as my old project. I uninstalled and re-installed VS2022. Same results. I reinstalled the v6 and v7 .net SDKs. No joy.

I tried running a `dotnet restore` but got "error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker. No packages exist with this id in source(s)" and same for Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, faced similar errors as you have:

[image]

Then, click on Nuget Package Manger like below:

[image]

Click on Settings Symbol:

[image]

Then click on plus symbol + and change to these:

In Name : **`nuget.org`**

In source: **`https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`**

[image]

After saving it, restart then Visual Studio, you will now be able to run azure functions like below:

[image]

For further you can refer [this](https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/uwp/online-getting-started/config-nugetpackage.html).

Comment: That fixed it in mor original project. The new test project I had made took more work to get some other references added - weird. But if I created a new project after your fix, it came out fine.

Comment: Gald, It worked for you!